# Make a text input resizeable for mobile?

Tags: html, forms

So I am doing a mobile site for my main site, but I wish for the site to be remained unchanged to its text input sizes, but for the mobile to be resizeable when using a mobile.

Here is my form code.

```
<form name="htmlform" method="post" action="thankyou.php" target="_blank">
<table width="447" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<td width="130"></tr>
<tr align="left" valign="top">
 <td height="30" align="left" valign="middle">Full Name</td>
 <td width="317" height="30" valign="middle">
  <input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="50"> </td>
</tr>

<tr align="left" valign="top">
 <td height="30" align="left" valign="middle"">Subject</td>
 <td height="30" valign="middle">
  <input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="100%" size="50"> </td>
</tr>
<tr align="left" valign="top">
 <td height="30" align="left" valign="middle">Email Address</td>
 <td height="30" valign="middle">
  <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="50" size="50"> </td>

</tr>
<tr align="left" valign="top">
 <td height="30" align="left" valign="middle">Contact Number</td>
 <td height="30" valign="middle">
  <input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="50" size="50"> </td>
</tr>
<tr align="left" valign="top">
 <td height="140" align="left" valign="middle">Content</td>
 <td height="140" valign="middle">
  <textarea  name="comments" cols="50" rows="8" wrap="VIRTUAL"></textarea> </td>

</tr>
<tr align="right" valign="middle">
 <td height="32" colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
   <div align="right">
     <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
   </div></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

> u can make 2 classes for all the inputs,and then use the jquery,to determine if the windowsize's width is a portable, small device or not,and toggle right classes accordingly to the size
>   (if u dont have a jquery knowledge,let me know,i will be more specific)

Comment: I have limited knowledge to be honest, so it would help thanks :)

Comment: jQuery is not necessary. OP should just use CSS @media queries and avoid bringing in jQuery just for this. I agree with your CSS classes point.

Comment: yeah thats true you can use css,here is an example
    @media all  (min-width: 800px) 
this select all media generally with a minimum width of 800px,so u can adjust the numbers...thank you jpod for the hint

Comment: this link will help you understand things better:  [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Comment: I genuinely cannot understand what you're trying to get across, sorry.

Comment: are you familiar with CSS?